# MySQLi prepare in if-statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am having a weird error. The following code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sold FROM Sales WHERE unitId = ? AND date = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('is', $unitId, $date);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1);
if ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
    // If something was fetched, it has already uploaded a value today so we need to update it
    echo "Existed!";
    $update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Sales SET sold = ? WHERE unitId = ? AND date = ?");
    var_dump($update);
} else {
    // It hasn't been inserted yet, so insert the new record
    echo "Not here man?!";
}
```

Says the $update is false, so the prepared statement with the update SQL did not return an object.

However, if i place that part before in the code, for example here:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sold FROM Sales WHERE unitId = ? AND date = ?");
$update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Sales SET sold = ? WHERE unitId = ? AND date = ?");
var_dump($update);
$stmt->bind_param('is', $unitId, $date);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1);
if ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
    // If something was fetched, it has already uploaded a value today so we need to update it
    echo "Existed!";
} else {
    // It hasn't been inserted yet, so insert the new record
    echo "Not here man?!";
}
```

Then it works? Now the var_dump says that $update is an object.

Why can't i do it after the fetch? Do i need to prepare all statements at once? I believe i am missing something fundamental here, which is why i am asking.

Hope someone can clarify.
Thank you

EDIT

---

I figured it out! I need to call free_result BEFORE i prepare another statement. However, i have no idea why, so i am leaving this question open to get a clarification. This code works, now i just need to know why:

```
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT sold FROM Sales WHERE unitId = ? AND date = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('is', $unitId, $date);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($col1);
if ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
    $stmt->free_result();

    // If something was fetched, it has already uploaded a value today so we need to update it
    $update = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Sales SET sold = ? WHERE unitId = ? AND date = ?");
    $update->bind_param('dis', $amount, $unitId, $date);
    if ( $update->execute() )
        echo "Success";
    else
        echo "Failure";
} else {
    // It hasn't been inserted yet, so insert the new record
    echo "Not here man?!";
}
```

Comment: Yea i know that, that is what i want to do, but if i do it comes up with an error since the $update variable isn't pointing to a real object. So i just showed the var_dump to verify that i narrowed it down to that problem, but i have no clue as to why the position matters.

Comment: Yes, I went wrong. Problem is: in first case when you say `bind_param('is', $unitId, $date);` the parameter for update is not available but in second case it's available since you are binding all the parameter at once.

Comment: How the problem is connected with binding parameters? The problem is that in first case `var_dump` should show `mysqli_stmt` object and not `false`.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that in the first case it is showing false! I have no idea why.

Comment: Check `mysqli->error` to get error description in case where `update` is false.

Comment: it says "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"? What does it mean?